# Issues with deploying GWT 2.7.0 app to Tomcat

Tags: gwt

When I run my GWT 2.7.0 app in Eclipse, all is fine.

I compile the app Right click on project > Google > GWT Compile. I build my war. Copy the war in the webapps directory.

I get the first page ok (static HTML), then when I click on the app, after some time, I get a message box that says:

```
The page at xxx:8081 says:

Couldn't load app from Super Dev Mode
server at http://xxx:9876.
Please make sure this server is ready.
Do you want to try again?
```

Comment: Have you ever used SuperDevMode with bookmarklets?

Comment: no... would it affect my issue?

Comment: It could I suppose. Bookmarklets store the "dev mode on" state in localStorage (or is it sessionStorage?), read at runtime by the *.nocache.js, so it could have affected you if you had ever used them.

Comment: I downgraded to GWT 2.6.1. I probably did something bad at some point, so I went back to a version I know a little better - Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what happened:

In debug / deployment mode, as I was working within eclipse, a library which **used to be** 100% compatible with GWT Client Side has evolved and is not anymore. It *seems* that the library was not recompiled while I was testing it (no need for recompilation) but when I compiled for deployment it did want to recompile the library, failed, but build the war anyway (probably lack of testing on the result), deployed the war, and got this error...

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem. And this happends because I generated the war file after deploying the project in Super Dev mode. The solution for me was to compile the project and generate the war before deploying it in Super Dev mode (which it is supposed to use the 9876 port not used in tomcat)