# GWT 2.7 Super Dev Mode not working while testing on the same network

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I recently began using GWT 2.7 in Eclipse Luna and I was running my projects seamlessly while testing them in localhost:8888, the thing is, when I tried to test them (any of them, even a new app with only the autogenerated content) with another device on the same local network using (pc running eclipse ip):8888 I get a message like this:

```
The page at (ip):8888 says: Couldn't load (app) from Super Dev Mode server at http://(ip):9876. Please make sure this server is ready. Do you want to try again?
```

This also happens when I try to access to the app in the pc running eclipse with (its own ip):8888.

I've checked [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631430/issues-with-deploying-gwt-2-7-0-app-to-tomcat) [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186577/gwt-2-7-gae-app-looks-for-codeserver-when-deployed) [similar](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/jaLOBSLdCyw) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30163968/how-enable-production-mode-in-gwt-2-7-application), but they didn't have any really helpful answers, these are a few things I've tried or discovered already:

- I enabled the 9876 port on the firewall
- I've deleted the .nocache.js and .devmode.js so that they're generated again
- I noticed that when this problem occurs it's because the browser can't get the (ip):9876/recompile-requester/(app) file
- I tried deploying the app to GAE and it doesn't work there either, nothing that happens on the modules Java code runs (And for some reason, I get a "Uncaught java.lang.ClassCastException" message on the chrome console, but this only happens on the deployed version, it doesn't happen on localhost:8888 or in (local ip):8888)

But nothing has worked and the four questions I mentioned are pretty much the only things related to this I've found, so I really don't know what else to try.

Comment: On mobile right now so can't write a full answer; search for devModeUrlWhitelistRegexp on SO (and GWT release notes).

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried adding this line to my .gwt.xml file but I still get the same problem `<set-configuration-property name="devModeUrlWhitelistRegexp" value="http://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1|192\.168\.150\.(\d{1,3}))(:\d+)?/?.*" />`

Comment: I now added a `-bindAddress 192.168.150.66` argument to the run config and now it only works there but not in localhost, is there any way to make it work on both?

Comment: Never mind that, I changed the -bindAddress for 0.0.0.0 and now everything works locally, it seems that the problem I have with the deployed app is a classcastexception during an initwidget in a UI for my app (which for some reason only occurs while deployed)

Comment: You should answer your own question if/when you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Thomas pointed out, the problem I had was that from GWT 2.6 onwards, if you want to test from other devices in the same network, you have to whitelist the addresses you'll be using in each *.gwt.xml file using a command line like this:

```
<set-configuration-property name="devModeUrlWhitelistRegexp" value="http://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1|192\.168\.150\.(\d{1,3}))(:\d+)?/?.*" />
```

I also had to add a `-bindAddress 0.0.0.0` attribute to the run config for it to work.

Comment: where did you add the -bindAddress 0.0.0.0 attribute ?